# Validate DTO in nestjs

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I'm using nest.js and typeORM to build my REST.API server. In my service I have some dto which comes from controller and make update in my db, but when I try to pass some unknown field in controller, I get an error:

```
EntityColumnNotFound: No entity column "hello" was found.at EntityColumnNotFound.TypeORMError [as constructor] (D
```

_

```
async edit(dto: EditThemeDto): Promise<Theme> {
    const { id } = dto;

    try {
      await this.themeRepository.findOneOrFail(id);
    } catch (e) {
      throw new NotFoundException(e);
    }

    await this.themeRepository.update(id, dto);
    return await this.themeRepository.findOne(id);
  }
```

Is there proper way to validate input data dto to entity schema?

Comment: Do you have your `Entity` to post also?

Comment: As well as both your create and update `DTO` objects?

Comment: use [pipes](https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes) to validate the incoming request payload before reaching the `edit` method. https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation#using-the-built-in-validationpipe

Comment: Post your DTO as @digitalextremist asked already.
You have to enable validation pipe and in the configuration enable option which is called "whitelistedOnly" or sth like that